# C#: how to take a screenshot of a portion of screen

Tags: c#, .net, screenshot

like

```
TakeScreenshot(new Rectangle(0,0,100,100), "output.jpg");
```

Comment: You need to specify is it WinForms, WPF or Silverlight.

Comment: I'm trying to create this method in a class library

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use the following:

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100);
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(rect.Width, rect.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
g.CopyFromScreen(rect.Left, rect.Top, 0, 0, bmp.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
bmp.Save(fileName, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Comment: what is "PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb" for?

Comment: PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb specifies that the format is 32 bits per pixel; 8 bits each are used for the alpha, red, green, and blue components.

Comment: This is the preferable solution, since it's only depending on the coordinates of the rectangle - and not the bounds of a primary screen.

Answer (score 11):

Here is the code to capture the screen. Change the values to the size you need.

```
 Bitmap printscreen = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);  

 Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(printscreen as Image);  

 graphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, printscreen.Size);  

 printscreen.Save(@"C:\printscreen.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Or make method which will return you captured image like this :

```
Image CaptureScreen(int sourceX, int sourceY, int destX, int destY, 
            Size regionSize)
{
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(regionSize.Width, regionSize.Height);
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
    g.CopyFromScreen(sourceX, sourceY, destX, destY, regionSize);
    return bmp;
}
 ......
 // call 
 Image image = CaptureScreen(sourceX, sourceY,  destX,  destY, regionSize);
 image.Save(@"C:\Somewhere\screen.jpg);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`Graphics.CopyFromScreen`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.copyfromscreen.aspx) method. Google turns up [this tutorial](http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial181_Capturing-screenshots-using-Csharp.html).

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the [Graphics.CopyFromScreen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.copyfromscreen.aspx) method?