# How to save a screenshot of a control to the clipboard?

Tags: c#, winforms

How to save a screenshot of a specific user control to the clipboard with `winforms` in `C#`?

To be clear the following is what I desire:

```
 public void SaveControlToClipboard(Control theControl){
     // Gets a bitmap of the control and saves it to the clipboard
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To copy a screen shot to the clipboard of an entire control, use the following function:

```
    private void CopyControlToClipboard(Control theControl)
    {
        // Copy the whole control to a clicp board
        Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(theControl.Width, theControl.Height);
        theControl.DrawToBitmap(bm, new Rectangle(0, 0, theControl.Width, theControl.Height));
        Clipboard.SetImage((Image)bm);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Using takeComponentScreenShot from https://stackoverflow.com/a/29315808/6468720

And than use Clipboard.SetImage(Image), MSDN link: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.clipboard.setimage?view=netframework-4.8